# Update of table fails when we are trying to update a field which is present in WHERE clause using bind variable, bind variable may be empty or not

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

I have a oracle table Emp which has 3 columns Name,State,Tech (all of Varchar2 datatype) .

When i am running the below query, update is not being performed properly.

How can i update field Name (or for matter, any of the 3 fields), depending on the corresponding bind variable being empty or not and corresponding field in the table being null or not.

SQL Code is as below:

```
UPDATE Emp
SET Name= :2
WHERE ((:2 is not null AND Name= :2) OR (:2 is null and Name is NULL)) 
  AND ((:3 is not null AND State = :3) OR (:3 is null and State is NULL)) 
  AND ((:4 is not null AND Tech = :4) OR (:4 is null and Tech is NULL));
```

Comment: Please explain the logic that you want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood the question: if parameter values are passed, then update that column to appropriate value. Otherwise, leave it "as is".

```
update emp set
  name  = nvl(:par_name, name),
  state = nvl(:par_state, state),
  tech  = nvl(:par_tech, tech);
```

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot, 
I tried the below query, i am trying to update name as MANU, i have 3 rows with name as null and satisfying the where clause.
But, name is not getting updated as MANU, its still null.

UPDATE Emp
SET Name  = nvl(:2, Name)
WHERE ((:2 is not null AND Name= :2) OR (:2 is null and Name is NULL)) 
  AND ((:3 is not null AND State = :3) OR (:3 is null and State is NULL)) 
  AND ((:4 is not null AND Tech = :4) OR (:4 is null and Tech is NULL));

Comment: Don't try *below query* but the one I suggested.

Comment: The above query works when name is null and to be updated with a value, but does not work when name has a value and has to be updated to null.

Comment: Does it mean that you want to set it to passed parameter value, regardless of what was written in it earlier? In other words: if NAME column's value was "Scott" and you passed NULL, you want to update it to NULL. If it was "Scott" and you passed "Mike", you want to update it to "Mike". If it was NULL and you passed "John", you want to update it to "John". If it was NULL and you passed NULL, it will remain null. Is that so?

Comment: You got it perfectly. I am looking for the same scenarios as you have explained. Regardless of what is there in the table for field Name (null or any non-null value), it should be updated with any non-null or null value

Comment: Then it is just `update emp set name = :par_name, state = :par_state, tech = :par_tech`

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that when the parameter value is `null`, then you don't want to update the corresponding column, I would recommend:

```
UPDATE Emp
    SET name = coalesce(:2, name),
        state = coalesce(:3, state),
        tech = coalesce(:4 tech),
    WHERE name <> :2 OR state <> :3  OR tech <> :4;
```

Comment: I am looking for both cases when name is null and to be updated with a value and  when name has a value and has to be updated to null

Comment: @Manu . . . You should probably ask a new question with a clear explanation, sample data, and desired results.